# Using MVC4 - best practice for updating model elements

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a web application being developed using c# MVC4 and jQuery/ AJAX. What I'd like to do is show a view to the user where they can update specific properties of a particular model without submitting an entire form. For example, one of the entity objects from the database is a "Task" class.  This class has several properties (TaskName, TaskDescription, etc.) The idea is to display a view that lists these properties and the user could click each one individually, revealing a text box populated with the property value that they could edit. I want to be able to save each edit on demand (using a button next to each text box) as needed and include validation on each field. How would I structure the controller / viewModel(s) to accommodate this? Would I have multiple controller functions for each field? One "edit" function to accept the entire model?

Comment: This is not a concrete problem. Start with learning MVC, and then you can use what you have learnt to solve this problem.
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started

Comment: Since these are the basics of ASP.NET MVC 4, I recommend you watch the superb video tutorials found on http://www.asp.net/mvc . You should start learning MVC before you ask questions about it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In reality, the amount of data in a submitted form is very small compared to most other components of a website, so there's not a problem in submitting an "entire form". You could submit your entire model back to your post action on each update (you can have multiple submit buttons for the same form), and a single controller action which will update your database with the new model.

However, if you do wish to update each component individually, then you can have individual forms for every value, which submit this value and a TaskId. These would submit to different actions, which will each have to find the model you want to update, and update it.

Personally I'd prefer the former, as it keeps your architecture simple and requires far less code.

Comment: Another problem that posting an entire form solves is the matter of *object-level validation*. In real-world applications you are rarely validating field-per-field, but often must validate an entire model object, since different fields can be mutually-exclusive, or more often, certain field values have side-effects in other fields, etc. So in order for a model to be consistent (logically, in terms of business rules) you must examine it in its entirety, and the simplest way to do that in a stateless manner is to post an entire object which either commits or fails as a whole.